# laravel updating table, connection refused

Tags: php, laravel

I am doing around 500 updates in a second

```
        \DB::table('media')
            ->where('model_id', $p->id)
            ->update(['file_name' => $f->imagePath, 'mime_type' => $mimet[$n[1]]]);
```

env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql 
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 
DB_PORT=3306 
DB_DATABASE=login 
DB_USERNAME=username 
DB_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

and I get this error:

```
Connection refused in file :

    Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused in file /mysite/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php on line 50
```

is it because of multiple updates or there is something else I'am missing here?

by the way doing the same amounts of inserts works well, but when I do updates it goes down, why is that?

Comment: can you share your env file?

Comment: @SpreadYourWings DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=login
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=mypassword

the connection works by itself, but for somereason it is refused at some times

Comment: Can you also show the working query? This will help checking any differences between use.

Answer (score 0):

Check the User privileges from the database.Specifically check if he user can update rows, and not just add them.

Comment: I think you should consider having this in the comment section and not an answer please

Comment: I've got all the privilegies

Comment: Can you share database.php contents?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
php artisan config:cache
composer dump-autoload
```

so,if it there any problem regarding cache or u forget to do autoload after changing something in your .env file.otherwise your .env file as you shown looks ok.

Comment: no it didnt helped, the thing is that when I do 500 inserts it is ok, if I do 1 update or 10 its ok, but when I do 500 updats it throws me that the connection is refused, I cant figure it out

Comment: @GerdenBarker please add your whole controller file.